# local server re-authenticating after restart using firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am trying to find a way to make my local server re-authenticate itself after restart,like in web app or phone app , if you close the app and open it again it will not need to re-login manually

the method i am using to authenticate my serve is similar to the firebase Docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-authenticate-with-firebase-in-nodejs

Comment: Please provide more details. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @bojeil if using firebase on web page or phone app for authentication , when you run the app and check the status of authentication you found that it`s already authenticate and you can redirect the user to another page, but on the server when you run it and check the state of the  authentication it return null  and need to use a web app to re-authenticate the server again